# Pullback induced by diffeomorphism is a symplectomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, diffeomorphism

> Show that if $\Phi:M\to M$ is a diffeomorphism, then the induced map $\Phi^*:T^*M\to T^*M$ is a symplectomorphism.

Presumably, $T^*M$ is equipped with the canonical 2-form $\omega$. To show $\Phi^*$ is a symplectomorphism, we must show it is a diffeomorphism and $(\Phi^*)^*(\omega)=\omega$. I am having trouble with the second part. The map $$(\Phi^*)^*:T^*(T^*M)\to T^*(T^*M)$$ takes a 1-form $\theta$ to $(\Phi^*)^*(\theta)$, where $$(\Phi^*)^*(\theta)X=\theta((\Phi^*)_*X)=\theta(X\circ\Phi^*)$$
for $X\in T(T^*M)$. And this map extends to two forms in the usual way:
$$(\Phi^*)^*(\omega)(X,Y)=\omega((\Phi^*)_*X,(\Phi^*)_*Y)=\omega(X\circ\Phi^*,Y\circ\Phi^*)$$ for $X,Y\in T(T^*M)$. So at first glance, it seems like I need to show that $\Phi^*$ is the identity, but surely this is not the case in general. So where have I gone wrong?

Comment: And what *is* the canonical $2$-form, after all?

Comment: @TedShifrin Let $\pi:T^*M\to M$ be the canonical projection map. Then the canonical 1-form is given by $\theta(X)_{(x,\phi)}=\phi(\pi_*(X))$ for $\phi\in T_x^*M$ and $X\in T_{(x,\phi)}(T^*M)$. We define the canonical 2-form to be the exterior derivative of theta: $\omega:=d\theta$.

Comment: So have you written out what that $2$-form evaluates to on a pair of tangent vectors?

Comment: @TedShifrin Well locally $X\in T(T^*M)$ looks like $X=a_k\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}+b_k\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k}$. And we can show then that $\omega=dp_j\wedge dx_j$. So if we take $X$ to be as above and set $Y=c_k\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}+d_k\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k}$, then $\omega(X,Y)=b_jc_j-d_ja_j$?

Comment: Well, if you're going to switch to local coordinates, then let's not worry about evaluating on vector fields. Calculate $\Phi^*(\sum dp_j\wedge dx_j)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think this is where I'm getting lost. I can calculate $\Phi^*(dp_j\wedge dx_j)(X,Y)=(dp_j\wedge dx_j)(X\circ\Phi,Y\circ\Phi)$ (I'm using the summation convention here). But because I know nothing about the form of $\Phi$, I'm not sure how to continue. I also looked at your global approach and was able to get to $\omega(X,Y)=X(\phi(Y\circ\pi))-Y(\phi(X\circ\pi))-\phi([X,Y]\circ\pi)$, but wasn't sure where to go from there.

Comment: Major suggestion: Learn how to pull back forms without pushing forward vector fields. That's a definition. That's not how you should compute. Next suggestion: Show that the canonical $1$-form is invariant under $\Phi^*$ (either way) and then it will follow that its exterior derivative is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have identified a flaw in my understanding of the pushforward that has allowed me to solve this problem. Perhaps someone can verify that this is correct.

For $X\in T(T^*M)$ and $(x,\phi)\in T^*M$, we have that $$(\Phi^*)^*(\theta)(X)_{(x,\phi)}=\theta((\Phi^*)_*X)_{(x,\phi)}=\phi(\pi_*((\Phi^*)_*X)).$$
But for $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$, $$\pi_*((\Phi^*)_*(X))f=(\Phi^*)_*(X)(f\circ\pi)=X(f\circ\pi\circ\Phi^*)$$
$$=X(f\circ\Phi\circ\pi)=\pi_*(X)(f\circ\Phi)=\Phi_*(\pi_*(X))f.$$
i.e.,
$$\pi_*((\Phi^*)_*(X))=\Phi_*(\pi_*(X)).$$ Then
$$(\Phi^*)^*(\theta)(X)_{(x,\phi)}=\phi(\pi_*((\Phi^*)_*X))=\phi(\Phi_*(\pi_*X))$$
$$=\Phi^*(\phi)(\pi_*X)$$ and I believe that this is the 1-form $\theta$ but on the other copy of $T^*M$.